# Gradle: How to get rid of duplicate classes error

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting the following duplicate class error when I run my Android application (I didn't include all the errors, but the duplicate errors are all coming from `org.apache.commons.lang3.*` and `org.apache.commons.logging.*`):

```
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.lang3.AnnotationUtils found in modules commons-lang3-3.4.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4) and commons-lang3-3.7.jar (commons-lang3-3.7.jar)
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.lang3.AnnotationUtils$1 found in modules commons-lang3-3.4.jar (org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4) and commons-lang3-3.7.jar (commons-lang3-3.7.jar)
...........
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable found in modules commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging-1.2.jar) and commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$1 found in modules commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging-1.2.jar) and commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$Entry found in modules commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging-1.2.jar) and commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$Referenced found in modules commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging-1.2.jar) and commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2)
Duplicate class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.WeakHashtable$WeakKey found in modules commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging-1.2.jar) and commons-logging-1.2.jar (commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2)
```

The error stems from this line of code in the gradle (I need to use the `docx4j` library because my app has to read in the contents of MS Word files selected by the user):

```
implementation "org.docx4j:docx4j:3.3.0"
```

Below is the complete code of my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.diffchecker"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'io.github.java-diff-utils:java-diff-utils:4.5'
    // For developers using AndroidX in their applications
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
    // For developers using the Android Support Library
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/commons-text-1.2.jar')
    //Thanks for using https://jar-download.com
    implementation 'org.webjars.bowergithub.telecomsante:pdf-viewer:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.tom_roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.1'
    implementation 'com.bskim:maxheightscrollview:1.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'

    implementation files('libs/commons-logging-1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/commons-lang3-3.7.jar')

    // Docx4j is the library used to read Word documents
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j
    implementation "org.docx4j:docx4j:3.3.0"
}
```

How do I use the `docx4j` library in my gradle without running into duplicate conflicts with the `commons-lang3` and `commons-logging` libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a similar way of what we did at the beginning but this time with both exclusions.

Try this:

```
implementation ('org.docx4j:docx4j:3.3.0') {
    ['org.apache.commons','commons-logging'].each {
        exclude group: "$it"
    }
}
```

Comment: None of the duplicate class errors relating to lang3.* are showing anymore... however the logging.* duplicate errors are still showing.

Comment: OK, I wasn't sure whether both were from that group or not (`org.apache.commons`), I've updated the answer trying to do multiple excludes this time

Comment: How would I go about using Groovy in my gradle? I searched some tutorials online but I haven't found a clear example.

Comment: When I place the compile() block in my gradle file (app-level) dependecies, I get the following error:  Could not find method compile() for arguments [build_difqk8gm93tw0xwozq61wfhvq$_run_closure3@208d78fa] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: Ok, could you try this way? It's a little tricky to exclude multiple groups, it's easier when it's only one

Answer (score 0):

Erase local lib and put this on the gradle

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3

implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.11'